# Wrap <td> text in <a> tag while avoiding nested elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use jQuery to wrap the text of a `<td>` element in an `<a>` element but there is also a `<span>` element nested inside of the `<td>` that I do not want to include in the `<a>` element.

[Here is a link to a jsfiddle with an example of my issue](https://jsfiddle.net/crowhead/ogkts0cf/3/)

```
<style>
  td {
    background-color: #bada55;
  }
</style>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="item"><span> + </span>First</td>
    <td class="item"><span> + </span>Second</td>
    <td class="item"><span> + </span>Third</td>
  </tr>
</table>

$(".item").wrapInner("<a href='#'/>");
```

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the text next to the span with:

```js
$('.item').contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3;
}).wrap("<a href='#'/>");
```

```css
td {
  background-color: #bada55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="item"><span> + </span>First</td>
    <td class="item"><span> + </span>Second</td>
    <td class="item"><span> + </span>Third</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What this does is loop over the table cells with class item, get the cell's contents (a span element and a text node), return the text node only, and wrap it with an anchor.